# Reading a file in unix

Tags: unix

I am completely new to Unix. I want to access my friends file whose `ls -l` gives:

```
-r--r----- 1 root filename
```

Note that I am not the root user and just a normal user. My question is how to read this file?
I tried to change the ownership by using `chown` and change the permission using `chmod` but it gives `Operation not permitted`.

Outputs of variuos commands :

```
$ ls -l 
total 4
-r--r----- 1 root abacus 373 Nov 12 19:19 abacus
$ groups
Wayne
$ cat abacus
abacus: Permission Denied
```

Comment: You can't.  You don't own the file and the permissions don't give access to anything other than the user and group who own it.

Comment: Is there some command by which I can know the group which I belong to ?

Comment: If your friend really agrees with you then he will apply other permissions to the file. Currently permission for you has been explicitly denied. There might be a reason for this. Ask him, if you agree that you should be able to read that file he might change the permissions.

Comment: @you can find out your groups woth the command `groups`.

Comment: @arkascha :Using the groups command lists me in the group ..So I should be able to read the file, but I cant

Comment: @WayneRooney Can you put the actual output of `ls -l` and `groups` into your questions? The `ls -l` you listed is either missing the group or the filename. Also try `getfacl file`, to see if there are any ACLs which grant or deny permissions beyond the usual Unix permissions. Also, what are you using to try to read the file? Just `cat` or `less`, or something else?

Comment: @Brian Campbell : I have made edits to the post...getfacl is not installed

Comment: @WayneRooney Thanks. One more comment; did you run the command "group" or "groups"? The command is generally called "groups".

Comment: @BrianCampbell : Yes I have made the corrections..Thank You

Comment: This question is part of an ongoing programming contest - Hacker Weekly Abacus http://hackerearth.com/hacker-weekly-abacus/. Here is the problem link - http://hackerearth.com/hacker-weekly-abacus/p-8/
And trust none of the above solutions will work, you have see the problem to crack

Comment: please dont reply to this post.This is a question from an ongoing contest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information given, it looks like you won't be able to read the file. The owner is `root`, and the group `abacus`; the file is set to be readable only by the owner and group. And it looks like you are not in the group; you are only in the group `Wayne`.

Unless your friend was asking you to try hacking his system (for instance, if he had left the `/etc/group` file world writeable, so you could add yourself to the `abacus` group), then you should not be able to read that file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the ownership of the file because you are not the superuser (root), and you do not already own the file.  If you could change the ownership/permissions on files you do not own, it would completely nullify the whole purpose of the permissions/ownership mechanism, which is computer security.

If you were operating a multiuser system, would you want your users to be able to muck about with files they do not own?  Would you like other users to modify your files without your permission?

Comment: Actually , we have had a bet on this.. He tells me that I can read the file , but I tried my best only to fail.. I am not trying to hack his system in anyway..

Comment: That means you must be a member of the group called abacus;  Seeing from the directory listing r--r--- I can see that the owner, and group members have read permissions -- no other permissions have been granted for this file.  The `groups' command will tell you all the groups to which you are currently a member...